# Yii - Form validation using renderPartial not working (processOutput=true already)

Tags: php, ajax, validation, yii

I'm rendering a form via ajax and renderPartial.
I noticed that the form no longer validates. Some searching led me to set processOutput to true, but the validation still isn't performed. This seems to be the answer for most people.

My action:

```
public function actionView($id){
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if(isset($_POST[$this->searchModel]))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST[$this->searchModel];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('/company/'.$model->company->company_id));
    }
    $this->renderPartial('view',array('model'=>$model), false, true);
}
```

and form:

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'person-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions' => array('validateOnSubmit'=>true),
)); ?>
<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'firstname'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'firstname',array('size'=>30,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'firstname'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

And finally the code loading the form:

```
<div class="form ajax-load hidden overlay"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.view').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.ajax-load').html('<img src="/images/spinner/search.gif"/>').show();
        $('.ajax-load').load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use a debugger?  Is the AJAX validation actually triggered?  Does your model have appropriate rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually caused because I had a duplicate form already on the page before I loaded the new form via ajax. One for new records and the one via ajax for updating records.

Once I removed the duplicate form the validation worked fine.

Hope this may help someone if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, **processOutput** loads javascript at **renderPartial**, and this ofc doesn't help you if you load this rendered *chunk with js* via ajax

I feel like this is what happens:

- Controller renders a view via **renderPartial**, adds javascript because of **processOutput** set to true
- Then your another view or controller or *whatever that loads ur form* just grabs this rendered chunk with js and of course doesn't trigger javascript in this chunk

So you have 2 choices:

1. Disable client validation since you're already have ajax form and rely only on submit validation
2. Manually reinitialise all form validation scripts after loading form